# The content of the view is shown below the sidebar

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having a problem.

I have the following Sidebar in a file called **navbar.blade.php**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                        <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2 </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Orders</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle ">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Bootstrap</span></a>
                        <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Products</span> </a>
                            <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="dropdown pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">loser</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col py-3">
            Content area...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have a second layout file (**layout.blade.php**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <x-navbar/>
    
    {{$slot}}    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Next I have the following view (*index.blade.php*) which I want to be shown not under the sidebar but in the space where there is the word `Content area ...` in the sidebar.

As I am doing, the contents of **index.blade.php** are shown below.

```
<x-layout>

@if (session('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
@endif

<div class="row margintitle">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1>List all customers</h1>                
    </div>
</div>

</x-layout>
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the x-slot tag

(refs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#slots)

I simplified the code:

**navbar.blade.php**:

```
<div class="col py-3">
    {{-- Content area... -- }}
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

**layout.blade.php**:

```
<x-navbar> 
    {{ $navbarContent }}
</x-navbar>

{{ $slot }}
```

**index.blade.php**:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-slot:navbar-content> navbar title </x-slot>   
    <div> other content </div>
</x-layout>
```

Comment: I get `$navbarContent undefined`